# Set some views which use Django Rest Framework API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a very basic Django Rest API.

I don't know how to have some HTML views, in the same django project, which uses API  (finally keeping API returning JSON only).

I followed this, but it seems to change the API View  (in this case, curl will retrieve HTML and not JSON) :
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer

Do I need another Django App ?  Another Django project ?  Some JS ?

EDIT :

Ok, I've seen it's possible, thanks to rrebase.

But I can't retrieve the JSON with Curl,  here my views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser

from . import models
from . import serializers

class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'profile_list.html'

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = models.CustomUser.objects.all()
        serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
        return Response({'profiles': queryset})
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

I get an error "Object of type 'CustomUser' is not JSON serializable"  when I request the API  (http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/)

Sorry, it's some different that initial question...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have both. The link you provided to docs has the following:

> You can use TemplateHTMLRenderer either to return regular HTML pages using REST framework, or to return both HTML and API responses from a single endpoint.

When making an API request, set the `ACCEPT` request-header accordingly to `html` or `json`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made some conditions in my view, and it's working

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()

        if request.accepted_renderer.format == 'html':
            data = {'profiles': queryset}
            return Response(data, template_name='profile_list.html')
        else:
            serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            data = serializer.data
            return Response(data)
```